# Array in Haskell defined with type (not data)

Tags: arrays, haskell

```
type Array a = Int -> a

emptyArray :: Array a
emptyArray i =
  error ("Access to non-initialized index " ++ show i)

putIndex :: Array a -> Int -> a -> Array a
putIndex ar i v = ar'
 where ar' j | j==i      = v
             | otherwise = ar j

getIndex :: Array a -> Int -> a
getIndex a i = (a i)
```

I don't understand the `emptyArray` and `putIndex` function. 
Problems are:

- what is the type of ar'
- when does the ar' pattern match?
- when is `j==i`?

  - `v` is of the type `a` or? In that case it would not return an array.
- what happens in otherwise = ar j
- why does  `getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 2` generate an error

  - `getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 1` returning 3 seems to be clear.

Comment: What do you expect `getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 2` to be, rather than an error? You haven’t put anything at index 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of answering all of your questions directly, I'll try to give an explanation to the rationale behind the `Array a` type here.

Arrays can be thought of as a data structure that has particular properties, namely that given an index it can return a value associated with that index.  This means that we can characterize an array by describing what values are associated with particular indexes, and this sounds very much like a function mapping an input (the index) to an output (the value at that index).  Hence, an array can be thought of as no different from a function, provided you don't want to know the length or what indices are valid.  This is a rather limiting definition of an array, but as a learning exercise it's important to see how data structures can be turned into functions by considering what their most important operations are.

> what is the type of `ar'`

Look at the type signature:

```
putIndex :: Array a -> Int -> a -> Array a
putIndex    ar         i      v  = ar'
```

So `ar :: Array a`, `i :: Int`, `v` :: a`, and`ar' :: Array a`.

> when does the `ar'` pattern match?

I assume you mean when does the definition of `ar'` get used.  `ar'` is an `Array a`, which means it's a function `Int -> a`.  Which means it gets used whenever `getIndex` is called on it.

> when is `j == i`?  `v` is the type of `a`?  In that case it would not return an array

Look carefully at the definition of `putIndex`.  `ar'` is the return value of `putIndex`, not `v`.  `v` is the return value of `ar'` when `j == i`.  `v` has type `a`, as you can tell from the type signature of `putIndex`.  `putIndex` is a function that augments an existing function `ar`, by adding a check first for when `i == j`.

> what happens in `otherwise = ar j`

If `j /= i`, then instead of returning `v` (the new value being associated with the index `i`), it looks up the value at index `j` in the original `ar`.  This might be more clearly stated as

```
putIndex originalArray indexToSet newValue = newArray
    where
        newArray j
            | j == indexToSet = newValue
            | otherwise       = getIndex originalArray j
```

> why does `getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 2` generate an error?

Essentially, you can turn index lookup into a bunch of nested if statements:

```
putIndex emptyArray i0 x0  ==>  \i -> if i == i0
                                    then x0
                                    else emptyArray i

putIndex (
    putIndex emptyArray i0 x0
    ) i1 x1                ==>  \i -> if i == i1
                                    then x1
                                    else if i == i0
                                            then x0
                                            else emptyArray i

putIndex (
    putIndex (
        putIndex emptyArray i0 x0
        ) i1 x1
    ) i2 x2                ==>  \i -> if i == i2
                                    then x2
                                    else if i == i1
                                            then x1
                                            else if i == i0
                                                    then x0
                                                    else emptyArray i
```

And so on, adding a new layer of `if-then-else` for every new `putIndex`.  For your specific example

```
putIndex emptyArray 1 3  ==>  \i -> if i == 1
                                    then 3
                                    else emptyArray i
```

Then

```
getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 2
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
if 2 == 1 then 3 else emptyArray 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The substitution helps a lot. So in this example an array is a cascade of `putIndex` functions and a `getIndex`call just specifies the `j` value to look through the  `if-then-else`construct. Which means that an `emptyArray foo` call will always appear (and fire an error) if no `putIndex foo array` call was done.

Comment: @froehli Correct, it's a big chain of if statements until `emptyArray` is hit.

Answer (score 4):

1. `ar' :: Int -> a`
2. always (there is only the `putIndex ar i v` pattern and this will match always)
3. well `j == i` if you call the resulting function/array at index `i` (it's the `i` from the call to `putIndex` - `j` is the argument for the local function `ar'`)
4. otherwise the **old** array/function `ar` is used (you see you change the array at just the index `i = j`
5. every index in `emptyArray` will generate an error - with `putIndex` you change this here for `i = 1` but afterwards you call it for `i= 2` so it will use the definition of `emptyArray` (your `otherwise` case above) which is the error
6. same situation as in 5 but here you call it with `i = 1` which you `putIndex` to 3

Maybe you understand it like this: `emptyArray` is a function that always `errors`

You can then use `putIndex` to get a new array/function based on it's first argument that will do just the same as this argument - only at index `i` it will now return `v` - for all other indizes `i` it will return `ar i` (the old function/array at *index* i).

`getIndex` really is just calling the function/array for *at an index*

Here is why `getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 2` is an error:

```
getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 2
= (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 2
{ inside putIndex you get i = 1, v = 3 and j = 2 here }
= emptyIndex 2
= error ...
```

but for `getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 1` it's:

```
getIndex (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 1
= (putIndex emptyArray 1 3) 1
{ inside putIndex you get i = 1, v = 3 and j = 1 here - so the `j == 1` case}
= 3
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your substitution helped to understand where the index comes from.